# To find basis of intersection of two subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was trying to solve the following problem.

$W_1 = \{(x,y,z) : y+2z =0\}$ and $W_2 = \{(x,y,z) : x+y+z =0\}$, where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ are two subspaces of $\mathbb{R^3}(\mathbb{R})$.

I need to find a basis of $W_1 \bigcap W_2$.

**My idea to solve the problem:** We need to solve the following system of linear equations

$y+2z = 0$ $~~~~~~~$ and  $~~~~~$  $x+y+z=0$

where linearly independent solution of this system will be a basis of 
$W_1 \bigcap W_2$. Is this the correct way to proceed? Can I solve this problem without involving matrix? What exactly is $W_1 \bigcap W_2$ here?

Kindly help. Any hint will be of great help. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Note that $W_1$ consists of vectors orthogonal to $(0,1,2)$, and $W_2$ of vectors orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$. So, in this particular case, you only need to calculate $(0,1,2)\times(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

y + 2z = 0 and x+y+z=0 are 2-d, so their intersection is 1-d and basis has only 1 vector.

Let's find it: say z = 1, from the first one we get y = -2, then x = 1.

Therefore, (1, -2, 1) will be the basis.

Answer (score 0):

$W_1\cap W_2$ here means those values of $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy both these sets of equations. The approach you outline of solving the system and obtaining independent solutions is precisely the way to go.